# Calling enum_dispatch'd instances of structs from main, outside of crate or file

Tags: rust, dynamic-dispatch, static-dispatch, enum-dispatch

If run without changes, `test_method()` is called correctly for both variants in the function `get_test_vector()`:

```
//! handler.rs
use enum_dispatch::enum_dispatch;

#[enum_dispatch]
trait CommonTrait {
    fn test_method(&self) {}
}

#[enum_dispatch(CommonTrait)]
pub enum StructEnum {
    First(FirstStruct),
    Second(SecondStruct),
}

pub struct FirstStruct {}
impl CommonTrait for FirstStruct {
    fn test_method(&self) {
        println!("First struct");
    }
}

pub struct SecondStruct {}
impl CommonTrait for SecondStruct {
    fn test_method(&self) {
        println!("Second struct");
    }
}

pub fn get_test_vector() -> Vec<StructEnum> {
    let struct_vec: Vec<StructEnum> = vec![
        StructEnum::First(FirstStruct {}),
        StructEnum::Second(SecondStruct {}),
    ];

    // These run fine
    struct_vec[0].test_method();
    struct_vec[1].test_method();

    return struct_vec;
}
```

```
//! main.rs
pub mod handler;
use handler::{get_test_vector, StructEnum};

fn main() {
    let returned_vec_from_func_call: Vec<StructEnum> = get_test_vector();

    // These calls fail: method not found in 'StructEnum'
    // returned_vec_from_func_call[0].test_method();
    // returned_vec_from_func_call[1].test_method();
}
```

The output of running this:

```
First struct
Second struct
```

But, un-commenting the `test_method()` calls within `main()` gives this error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `test_method` found for enum `StructEnum` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:9:36
  |
9 |     returned_vec_from_func_call[1].test_method();
  |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `StructEnum`
  |
 ::: src/handler.rs:9:1
  |
9 | pub enum StructEnum {
  | ------------------- method `test_method` not found for this
  |
  = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `CommonTrait` defines an item `test_method`, perhaps you need to implement it
```

I could match on `StructEnum` but this would create duplicate code, and with a large number of types and a large number of methods with different implementations of the same methods. Perhaps I'm just approaching this situation entirely wrong?

Comment: As the linked Q&A indicates, the trait must be in scope for you to call its methods. So make `CommonTrait` public and import it into main via `use handler::CommonTrait;`.

Comment: @justinas It does! Calling the trait function directly works perfectly in the example and in my larger application. Thanks for the link, that's much appreciated.